# How to create a FactoryBot factory that is an amalgamation of two other records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, factories

I have an object, let's call it a TransitProvider.

It isn't an ActiveRecord object. It uses ActiveModel but it's designed to pull (or persist) it's data from two separate tables, a Provider table and a TransitService table. (reason being: the concept of "Transit Provider" is a concept that is made up of a Provider that offers a Transit Service).

So this is working well, except when I try to build a Factory (using FactoryBot) for the TransitProvider.

It doesn't have a table, so I can't "create" one. Instead, I'd need to actually create the underlying Provider and TransitService.

But I don't know how to do that in FactoryBot.

I want to be able to do stuff like:

```
let(:transit_provider) { create(:transit_provider, name: "Some Name") }
```

and have it "under the covers" actually create the Provider and the TransitService and then populate the ActiveModel TransitProvider with data from both.

Help?!

Comment: BTW, the `Provider` class `has_one` `TransitService` but the `TransitProvider` class is just a wrapper of both. Since it isn't an ActiveRecord object, I didn't define any associations on it. Otherwise that might have been easier. I found plenty of examples of how to handle factories with associations. But this is really an abstract-like factory that underneath needs to create/build two separate factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughtbot recently wrote a [blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tips-for-using-factory-bot-without-an-orm) on this subject, and  FactoryBot's README has a section on [creating factories for non-AR Ruby classes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction). Notably, the implementation relies on `initialize_with` to instantiate the factory using a custom block, rather than the default behavior of calling `new` without any arguments on what is assumed to be an AR model.

In your scenario, I would imagine a `TransitProvider` factory that looks something like:

```
factory :transit_provider do
  provider { create(:provider) }
  transit_service { create(:transit_service) }

  initialize_with { new(provider, transit_service) }
end
```

Also important to note that `create` will never work for the above factory since that attempts to instantiate a model and persist a record in the DB. You'll want to `build` this factory instead.

Comment: You can customize `create`, see [Custom Methods to Persist Objects](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-methods-to-persist-objects). You could – for example – use `build(:provider)` / `build(:transit_service)` and save those in the `to_create` hook. That way you would have both, a working `build` and `create`.